# Need data in a specific manner

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have data in table :

```
A    B    c
1    2    3,4,5
11   12   13,14
```

I want data to be converted like:

```
A   B     C
1   2     3
1   2     4
1   2     5
11  12    13
11  12    14
```

Comment: Great! Those comma separated items are a mess.

Comment: I want a question to be like that https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ))

Comment: Look at the LISTAGG().

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, you have an Oracle silver badge, while I only have a bronze one.

Comment: While there are (ugly) ways of doing this within Oracle, it might even be easier to handle outside the database.  Maybe you can find a way to reimport your data in a normalized format.

Comment: I also think it's a dupe. I have an SQL gold badge but little to no experience with Oracle so don't look at me, I'm not going to close this one :-)

Comment: If it were tagged Oracle 12c, I would not have closed it, because there are other solutions possible in that version.